# Give different color to each country in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Does anyone know how to give a different color to each country in a google map?

e.g:

in the world map

Blue overlay to  UK, then RED china...etc

I wonder if google provide API to give color to each country

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44308091/assign-different-color-to-each-country-in-the-google-map-api?rq=1) will be useful.

Answer (score 13):

Using Google Maps this is really not easy, as @oezi said you would need to build overlays of every country you want to color, which frankly sounds like a mess.

But if you don't need all of the functionalities of Google Maps, <s>perhaps you can use a [Map Chart](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/gallery/new_map_charts.html) from the fantastic **Google Chart Tools** (aka **Chart API**). You can check and tinker with a working example of a Colored Map (among some others) in the interactive [Chart Wizard](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/chart_wizard.html)</s>

**2017 UPDATE**: This answer is quite old and as such the Map Charts API has been deprecated by Google. You can use the **Geocharts** from the [Google Charts API](https://developers.google.com/chart/) instead:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

Hope this helps!

Comment: Here's a great site to help you generate your UI: [mapstyle.withgoogle.com](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/)

Answer (score 5):

you may check this question,it's the same question you are asking.
[How to color countries using google maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739830/how-to-color-countries-using-google-maps)

it's talking about google Geocharts in google maps.

Answer (score 2):

there is a possibility to change the [map style](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#StyledMaps). and there is a very nice interactive example [here](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) - but, as far as i can see, it isn't possible to change the style of a specific country using this, so you'll have to build your own [overlays using polygons](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays.html#Polygons_Overview).

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 2):

First, find the shape file in .kml format. Tip: try googling "kml uk" or "kml china".

Once you have the KMLfile, host it somewhere and then call it as a `var` inside your Google Maps API initMap like this:

```
var myCustomRegion = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'FULL_URL_TO_YOUR_SHAPE_FILE',
    map: map
});
```

Now your shape is laid into your map.

You can style the shape using the `<LineStyle>` and `<PolyStyle>` tags inside the KML file itself.